# Editing the XLS sometimes changes date format

Tags: phpexcel, xls, date-formatting

I am editing an XLS template from php using PHPExcel, on the server, and after I fill in the data, save the file and send it to the user. The problem occurs, sometimes, when the user submits back the form after editing something in the XSL file. What sometimes happens is the date format changes.
[image]

Don't know what is causing this, whether the OS or the client used to edit the file, but what is to be done to prevent this date format to change and remain the same across all three cells? Thanks in advance!

```
private function setDateInCell(\PHPExcel_Cell $cell, \DateTime $date)
{
    $excelDate = \PHPExcel_Shared_Date::PHPToExcel($date);
    $cell->setValue($excelDate);
    $cell->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2);
}
```

**EDIT:** If I can't prevent the date format change, I should at least be able to read the date as a date object, regarding of format. Can this be done?

Comment: No spaces, I am using format('Y-m-d') function to write the date

Comment: There are no other date fields in the document

Comment: Not really :( No idea. I also tried freezing the date fields as these 3 date fields should not be edited but the cell freezing only works on a newly created XLS, not on the template I am using, what's with that?

Comment: Cell "protection" (not freezing, that's something different entirely) shouldn't care whether you're creating and saving a PHPExcel object, or loading and saving a PHPExcel object.... the PHPExcel object in question neither knows nor cares whether it was created using `new PHPExcel()` or loaded via a Reader.... so the save will __not__ work any differently

Answer (score 1):

I hope you're not using `Y-m-d` format to write the date, but writing an actual Excel serialized date/time stamp value to the cell and setting the number format mask to set the format for a date. That is the expected approach to date handling. Writing a `Y-m-d`-formatted value is writing a **string** value that humans *might* interpret as a date, but it isn't a date to MS Excel.... and if MS Excel does recognise it as a date, it might convert it to a serialized date/time stamp value and choose its own formatting, which is typically locale-specific.

But making those cells protected is certainly one way of preventing user activity from changing values and/or formatting

Comment: Thanks, actually I was using 'Y-m-d' php format. Oops. Will fix it. Thanks for the quick reply Mark!

Comment: Nope, I updated the date input to $cell->getStyle()->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode(\PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_DATE_YYYYMMDD2); but still, on a Windows machine, using a microsoft office, if I double click on the date cell, it changes format to MM/DD/YYYY

Comment: Ensure that your cell value is actually an MS Excel date/time stamp, not a formatted string value

Comment: Please see my edited question, I added the code that inserts the date into cells, as you said. Still changing after double click on the windows machine.